# HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error when return object

Tags: java, json, rest, object, glassfish-4

I noticed this glassfish error that is due to the REST methods where I return an object with which I produce json:

```
@GET
@Path("/myUrl")
@Produces("application/json")
MyObject getObject(@Context UriInfo info){
...
return new MyObject(...);
}
```

how to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Check your log files.

Comment: Check whether your `MyObject` is being initialized with `@XmlRootElement`. Your response object is not getting mapped properly with your entity.

Comment: With @XmlRootElement is the same problem. I use com.sun.jersey (servlet, json ...). Now I return a string and use gson to convert my object in a string, it's working